index.js:683 Uncaught Error: Page "/[[...slug]]/page" is missing param "/" in "generateStaticParams()"
I am going to merge the React website with the Next.js website and getting title error in console and terminal this is the error:

index.js:683  Uncaught Error: Page "/[[...slug]]/page" is missing
param "/" in "generateStaticParams()", which is required with "output:
export" config.
at DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (file://F:\NEXT.JS\vpatomic\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1032:27)

This is what I followed a document Migrating from Create React App in react src folder I created a app folder In app folder I created layout.js and [[...slug]] folder in [[...slug]] folder created client.js and page.js file.
client.js:
import React from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const App = dynamic(() => import("../../App"), { ssr: false });

export function ClientOnly() {
  return <App />;

page.js:
import "../../index.css";
import { ClientOnly } from "./client";

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ slug: [""] }];
}

export default function Page() {
  return <ClientOnly />;
}

